# Why isn't systemd parsing my override config as expected?

Tags: systemd

The following phenomena are reproducible on an Arch Linux as well as on Ubuntu Artful and I therefore conclude that I'm not getting a detail on `systemd`, again.

I simply want to add a command to be executed after a Docker daemon was started as `systemd` service.

I invoke an editor with `systemctl edit docker.service` and for the means of evaluation I enter this:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=true
```

There is a `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` file now with that content and I also invoke `systemctl daemon-reload` to be sure.

Now I display the parsed unit with `systemctl show docker.service` and no `ExecStartPost` directive appears in the output, though I would expect it. A `systemd-analyze verify` yields nothing.

So, why is the `ExecStartPost` from the override file not considered as a part of the unit by `systemd`?

To test whether the file with the overriding directives is actually evaluated, I tried this content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=foo
```

To my confusion, the `ExecStart` directive is now missing in the output of `systemctl show docker.service`.

Can someone explain to me why the first directive seems to be considered while the second isn't in this case?

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was apparently that I didn't specify an absolute path to the command such as:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=/bin/true
```